# Set Range according to Bold format in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, format, with-statement

I am trying to build a report that can:
1. loop through the individual dates 
-----and set each date as a range. 
2. I need the loop to find all rows within the range 
-----with the value "Individual", 
-----sum the corresponding value in column D of each row with Individual 
-----and paste this summed value in another sheet. 
3. If the value (individual) is not found, 
-----the output cell needs to shift down one row, 
----------without filling in anything (or filling in 0) so the dates will match up at the end. 
----------(If the output cell does not shift down, 
---------------the output data will be showing values for the wrong dates.)

**Data source set up**: 
**The problem with the data** I have is that it is **formatted inconsistently**. 
This means that the ***first row*** will be different at times. although it will ***always begin with "Individual.."***. The one consistency I do have is that the ***dates are formatted bold***.

**Screenshot of the raw data**: [image]

**Problem**:
The code I have works perfectly well, if the first row after the date is called "Individual Return Guest". However, if not the case, it of course skips a few dates and gives an incorrect output. I think the best way of looping through the data would be by setting the range according to the Bold format.

**Question**:
How can I do this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub mm()
Dim iArea As Long

With Worksheets("FC01.RPT")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2) = "Individual Rate Guest"
    With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Individual Rate Guest"
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(-1)
            For iArea = 1 To .Areas.Count - 1
                With .Parent.Range(.Areas(iArea).Offset(1), .Areas(iArea + 1).Offset(-1))
                    Worksheets("Plan").Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Cells, "Individual*", .Offset(, 3))
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).ClearContents
End With
End Sub
```

I am open to suggestions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could try the Find method which has a searchformat parameter. Or you could loop through until you find the first bold cell.

Comment: I'd look through and find the bold property and if the next row begins with individual. not sure filters meet your request... for loop to identify the bold... while loop to identify next cell down for the individual - if met then identify range